# Archiving to another workbook in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an archive workbook once a column (V) is marked as "Yes". I had the macro functioning but when I tested it again this afternoon I received the out of range error. I have checked the names of my workbook/worksheet, they are correct and both workbooks are in the same folder. I've tried to troubleshoot and I've discovered that it only runs when both workbooks are open. Is there a way that this could run without the archive workbook being open?(I'm brand new to VBA and am teaching myself, so any help is appreciated!)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 22 Then
  If Target = "Yes" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
  nxtRow = Workbooks("FPPE Archive.xlsm").Worksheets("EUHM Onboard").Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
   Target.EntireRow.Copy _
Destination:=Workbooks("FPPE Archive.xlsm").Worksheets("EUHM Onboard").Range("A" & nxtRow)
   Target.EntireRow.Delete
End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How would your macro run if the book holding it is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the code in your question is written requires the Archive Workbook to be open for it to work.

The refactored code below should give you want you need. It will open the archive workbook each time it's needed, update it, then close it.

You can make it a bit nicer by checking first to see if the workbook is already open. *(there are functions all over the internet for that)*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Column = 22 and Target = "Yes" Then

      Application.EnableEvents = False

      Dim wb as Workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FPPE Archive.xlsm"

      Dim ws as Worksheet
      Set ws = wb.Worksheets("EUHM Onboard")

      nxtRow = ws.Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

      Target.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A" & nxtRow)

      Target.EntireRow.Delete

      wb.Close True

      Application.EnableEvents = True      

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, I have been using your code when I was working out some kinks on other things and I tested it again this afternoon I received the out of range error. I have checked the names of my workbook/worksheet and they are correct. I've tried to troubleshoot but now when I select "Yes" in column V, the macro doesn't register at all. What could be the issue? The highlighted line is the "Set wb=..."

Comment: `the macro doesn't register at all` - make sure `Application.EnableEvents = True`. You can use the immediate window to set this back. If your code broke mid-stream, it may not have turned it back on. For the error, make sure the workbook path and name are valid with your directory.